# Finding probability from joint distribution

Tags: statistics

f( x , y ) = 5/4( x^2 + y ) ; 0 < y < 1 - x^2

I need to find P( Y < X +1 ).

Well I started using double integration with Y's range being from 0 to x+1 and X's range being from -1 to 1. But somehow the answer isn't coming. 
Help is Appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What you've written down is not a density. Integrating over the support gives $5$ and not $1$.

Comment: Flowsnake I've solved the problem and the density is all right. Thank you for seeing it though.